# R: Function as argument of another function

Tags: r, function

I have written the R function `myplot()` which draws a curve corresponding to the supplied function `FUN` over the interval [-10, 10].

```
myplot <- function(FUN)
{
  curve(FUN(x), xlim = c(-10, 10))
}
```

For example

```
myplot(FUN = dnorm)
```

gives

[image]

How can I add arguments to `FUN`? For example, let's say I want to plot the normal density with mean 5.

Following @akrun's comment, I can do something like that:

```
myplot <- function(FUN, ...)
{
  args <- list(...)
  curve(FUN(x, unlist(args)), xlim = c(-10, 10))
}
myplot(dnorm, mean = 5)
```

But then

```
   > myplot(FUN = dnorm)
    Error in FUN(x, unlist(args)) : 
      Argument non numérique pour une fonction mathématique
```

Also, `myplot(FUN = dnorm, mean = 5, sd = 2)` does not give the expected picture...

Comment: Try `dots <- list(...);
  curve(FUN(x, unlist(dots)), xlim = c(-10, 10))`

Comment: @akrun: Thank you! I have edited my post with further questions. Thank you again.

Comment: If you have a different question post a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original function works fine (but your original example had a typo)

```
myplot <- function(FUN, ...)
{
    curve(FUN(x, ...), xlim = c(-10, 10))
}

myplot(dnorm)
myplot(dnorm, mean = 5)
myplot(dnorm, mean = 5, sd=2)
```

all seem to work.